# How to correctly annotate this function for swagger?

Tags: swagger, swagger-php

I am trying to write a little Api using Slim. I want to have it documented very well so I installed swagger-php and UI and investigated on it the last days. For some reason my petstore demo is missing all the post annotations. My API will look like in this example:

http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/restful-services-with-jquery-php-and-the-slim-framework/

How would the swagger annotations for the addWine() function look like? 
How do I annotate the result of the function (last insert id), since it is no model ?

An example would be really great.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This would do it. Propably not ment to be like this, but doing exactly what I wanted.

```
/**
* @package
* @category
* @subpackage
*
* @SWG\Resource(
*   apiVersion="1.0.0",
*   swaggerVersion="1.2",
*   basePath="http://myapi",
*   resourcePath="/hello",
*   description="Giving you your name in case you forgot it",
*   produces="['application/json','application/xml','text/plain','text/html']"
* )
*/

/**
 * @SWG\Api(
 *   path="/hello/{yourname}",
 *   @SWG\Operation(
 *     method="GET",
 *     summary="Gives you your name",
 *     notes="Returns your name",
 *     type="hello",
 *     nickname="yourname",
 *     @SWG\Parameter(
 *       name="yourname",
 *       description="Enter your name",
 *       required=true,
 *       type="text",
 *       paramType="path"
 *     ),
 *     @SWG\ResponseMessage(code=404, message="Bad, really bad name.")
 *   )
 * )
 *
     */ 

 /**
     * @package
     * @category
     * @subpackage
     *
     * @SWG\Model(id="hello",required="name")
     */

/**
 * @SWG\Property(name="name",type="string",description="Your name")
 */
```